# What will happen if there was no crust?

Tags: science-based

What will happen if this planet's crust vanished? Will the mantle turn to solid or will life melt and collapse?

Comment: The answer to this is going to be "we all die."  However, how we die is up to you.  How do you want the crust to vanish?  What process does it undergo?  How fast does this occur?

Comment: @CortAmmon This is the correct answer. Depending on what magical events cause the crust to vanish and what happens to everything above the crust, we can die of falling (depth of crust), we can die of (FIRE!), or we can die of much more complicated thermodynamic and astrophysics problems arising from the Earth suddenly losing a bunch of heat and mass.

Answer (score 4):

Well, everyone and everything that hasn't vanished falls 20 to 30 miles, and dies of that. The oceans fall less distance, because the crust is thinner there, only 3 to 6 miles.

If something miraculously lowers people, plants, animals, building and the oceans gently to the new surface of the earth, everyone still dies, because the upper layer of the crust is at about 500 centigrade, and everything is cooked, melted, or evaporated.

Comment: A few miles of seawater hitting the mantle at 400 m/s would be a pretty impressive show.

Answer (score 1):

It would take a while for a new crust to solidify, so yes...  most life would probably perish assuming no place to escape to.  Initially, the temperature would increase considerably on the surface of the planet.  This would slowly diminish as a new crust formed, but we're talking probably tens of thousands of years or longer before anything habitable would be available.

Comment: The crust collapse or simply poof disappear what happens then?